# The sum from 1 to n in theta(log n)

Tags: algorithm

Is there anyway to calculate the sum of 1 to n in Theta(log n)?

Of course, the obvious way to do it is sum = n*(n+1)/2.

However, for practicing, I want to calculate in Theta(log n).

For example,

```
sum=0; for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) { sum += i}
```

this code will calculate in Theta(n).

Answer (score 0):

Fair way (without using math formulas) assumes direct summing all n values, so there is no way to avoid O(n) behavior.

If you want to make some **artificial** approach to provide exactly O(log(N)) time, consider, for example, using powers of two (knowing that  `Sum(1..2^k = 2^(k-1) + 2^(2*k-1)` - for example, `Sum(8) = 4 + 32`). Pseudocode:

```
function Sum(n)
   if n < 2 
       return n
   p = 1     //2^(k-1)
   p2 = 2    //2^(2*k-1)
   while p * 4 < n:
      p = p * 2;
      p2 = p2 * 4;
   return p + p2 +                    ///sum of 1..2^k
         2 * p * (n - 2 * p) +        ///(n - 2 * p) summands over 2^k include 2^k
         Sum(n - 2 * p)               ///sum of the rest over 2^k
```

Here `2*p = 2^k` is the largest power of two not exceeding `N`. Example:

```
Sum(7) = Sum(4) + 5 + 6 + 7 = 
         Sum(4) + (4 + 1) + (4 + 2) + (4 + 3) = 
         Sum(4) + 3 * 4 + Sum(3) = 
         Sum(4) + 3 * 4 + Sum(2) + 1 * 2 + Sum(1) = 
         Sum(4) + 3 * 4 + Sum(2) + 1 * 2 + Sum(1) = 
         2 + 8  +   12   + 1 + 2 +   2 +     1 = 28
```